# How to fix Redefinition and Multiple Initialization Errors with VertexShader and PixelShader in Visual Studio C++?

Tags: c++, shader

I am working on a code and when it try debugging I keep getting errors that the VertexShader and PixelShader are either having multiple initialization errors or redefinition errors depending on how I try and fix them. No matter what tho the errors will not go away. This code is the only area that has these so they are not anywhere else in my entire code.

```
void (*VertexShader)(VERTEX&) = 0;
void (*PixelShader)(A_PIXEL&) = 0;

Matrix4x4 SV_WorldMatrix;
Matrix4x4 SV_ViewMatrix;
Matrix4x4 SV_PerspectiveProjection;



void applyPerspective(VERTEX& v)
{

    v = MatrixVertesMultiply(v, SV_WorldMatrix);
    v = MatrixVertesMultiply(v, SV_ViewMatrix);
    v = MatrixVertesMultiply(v, SV_PerspectiveProjection);

    v.Position.x /= v.Position.w;
    v.Position.y /= v.Position.w;
    v.Position.z /= v.Position.w;
    v.Position.w /= v.Position.w;
};

A_PIXEL PS_White(A_PIXEL& makeWhite)
{
    A_PIXEL whitePixel = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    makeWhite = whitePixel;
    return whitePixel;
};
```

Code will run without redefinition or multiple initialization errors